# FUNCTION in WHERE clause of SQL query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following (private) PL/SQL function (inside PACKAGE) returning the previous month in 'YYYYMM' format:

```
FUNCTION GET_PREV_MONTH RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM');
END GET_PREV_MONTH;
```

I need to compare if records are from previous month in several my queries so I wanted to make private function returning previous month. Why I cannot use this return value from GET_PREV_MONTH() function in WHERE clause of my other SQL queries like:

```
UPDATE mytable t SET t.col=1
WHERE TO_CHAR(t.created,'YYYYMM')=GET_PREV_MONTH();
```

Oracle says **PLS_00231: function 'GET_PREV_MONTH' may not be used in SQL**.

If I create this, this works!

```
UPDATE mytable t SET t.col=1
WHERE TO_CHAR(t.created,'YYYYMM')=TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: Please show us the content of `GET_PREV_MONTH` function.

Comment: You don't see my function code above in thread?

Comment: Sorry, I had to miss it.

Comment: Don't compare dates in string form, compare dates as dates.  If the column is a date and it is indexed you will lose the ability to make use of the index.   WHERE t.created >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)) AND t.created < TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)) + 1

Comment: OK, thanks @unleashed for your advice not to compare dates in string form. However, your WHERE clause will not select all records from previous month but from one day that was exactly one month ago.

Comment: You are correct, to cover the entire month, adjust the from and to dates like the following  `WHERE t.created >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MON') -- greater than the start of the previous month
  AND t.created < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MON')               -- less than the start of the current month`

Comment: @unleashed or simply `WHERE t.created BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MON') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON')`, I will edit my function according to your recommendation, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to make private function returning previous month. Why I cannot use this return value from `GET_PREV_MONTH()` function in `WHERE` clause of my other SQL queries

It is a private function - you cannot reference it outside the package.

If you want to use it in SQL then declare it in the package specification so that it is public.

> This is private function of this package! This function is used in procedures from the same package. It is not referenced outside this package.

It **CANNOT** be used in the SQL context if it is not a public function; regardless of whether the SQL is being called from inside or outside the same package.

Comment: To expand on your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130165/how-to-declare-a-public-and-a-private-item-inside-a-package

Comment: This is private function of this package! This function is used in procedures from the same package. It is not referenced outside this package.

Comment: @sbrbot That makes no difference. You can use it in a PL/SQL context within the same package but if you are using it in an SQL context then the function must be public (regardless of whether that SQL context is instantiated from a PL/SQL context inside the package).

Comment: OK, thanks, I was not aware of different contexts (PL/SQL and SQL contexts). I will check this now.